# Why to use variable hinting in Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5

PHP is not a strict typing language right? I am working with Laravel 5.1 and PHP 7.2

I would make my route like this

```
Route::get('/getSizes', 'JobTickeController@getSizes')->name('getSizes');
```

in `JobTicketController` there I define my function as below

```
public function getSizes(Request $response){

}
```

My question is even if PHP is not a strict typing (by default) why should I define `Request` variable type before `$request` variable? This code throws an exception with out the type hinting `Request`.

Comment: where did you read that loose thing?

Comment: Loose type???!!

Comment: now the question is fine right ?

Comment: I think this is related more to "Why to use strict typing PHP". Following link might find answer for that. https://www.quora.com/Are-strict_types-in-PHP-7-not-a-bad-idea I would also like add, it makes debugging lot easier if you define what type the variable should be and might even block bugs happening in first place.

Comment: Why still the vote down??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although others go into the fact that PHP is not a strictly typed language, there's no answer to why the type hinting is necessary.

What happens in your Laravel app is the following. Laravel will attempt to hit the `getSizes` method in your controller by resolving any typehinted arguments from ["the (Service) Container"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container) also known as IoC. In case it finds no bindings, it will attempt to instantiate the class. Any arguments that have no type hinting are assumed to be ["route parameters"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).

As your route has no parameters, the `$request` cannot be given any value without being typehinted. When you type hint the `$request` argument with the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class Laravel will automatically resolve that binding from its container and make it available inside your method.

TLDR:

- Your exception is thrown in case you don't typehint because there's no route parameter to use as value.
- Using typehinting will have Laravel automatically resolve a binding from the container or instantiate the class if it has not been bound.

See Method Inject in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers).

Comment: this answer explain it a lot

Answer (score 0):

First there is nothing named `Loose Type`, but you can say `PHP is not a strictly typed language` like `JAVA` for example.
In your example, that is `a Type Hinting`, so here you force the function to accept parameters with type `Request` only.